# count real total customer by product groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

first of all, i'm not really sure if this possible or not.
let say I have this dataset example

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION(
user_id numeric,
account_id varchar,
product varchar,
colour varchar,
price numeric);
insert into transaction (user_id, account_id, product, colour, price)
values
(1, 'a1', 'biycle', 'black', 500),
(1, 'a2', 'motorbike', 'red', 1000),
(1, 'a2', 'motorbike', 'blue', 1200),
(2, 'b3', 'car', 'grey', 10000),
(2, 'b2', 'motorbike', 'black', 1250),
(3, 'c1', 'biycle', 'black', 500),
(3, 'c2', 'biycle', 'black', 525),
(3, 'c4', 'skateboard', 'white', 250),
(3, 'c5', 'scooter', 'blue', 260)
```

from that table we know that
the total real customer is 3 (1,2,3) and
the total real account is 8 (a1, a2, b3, b2, c1, c2, c4, c5)
and then with this code

```
SELECT
    product,
    colour,
    sum(price)total_price,
    count(DISTINCT user_id)customer_total,
    count(DISTINCT account_id)account_total
 from transaction
 group by 
    product, colour
```

and the return is like this

| product | colour | total_price | customer_total | account_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| biycle | black | 1525 | 2 | 3 |
| car | grey | 10000 | 1 | 1 |
| motorbike | black | 1250 | 1 | 1 |
| motorbike | blue | 1200 | 1 | 1 |
| motorbike | red | 1000 | 1 | 1 |
| scooter | blue | 260 | 1 | 1 |
| skateboard | white | 250 | 1 | 1 |

from the output above,
if we total the customer_total, it will be 8 and
if we total the account_total, it will be 9

is there any alternative way so that the customer_total will be 3 and account_total will be 8

Comment: Can you update your post with an expected output? If you don't have such expected output, the question becomes opinion-based.

Comment: You can read between the lines where he mentioned total real customer is 3 and total real account is 8.

Comment: @jose_bacoy It's possible that the result shown in your answer is desired. But I agree the OP should add this to the question to make it clear.

Comment: Agree to wait and see what Napier does.

Comment: first I'm gonna say sorry, to be honest, I dont really have any idea about the exact output, kinda confusing and ambiguous. but with the answer that have been provided by jose_bacoy, I kinda have some enlightenment with my another cases.
for this case, kinda hard to explain it, maybe I would say that, its kinda impossible to show the output in one table.
the output will be, if we sum the rows from customer_total and account_total it will return the exact real customer and account, which is 3 and 8, but in the other hand, it need to maintain the product and colour customer and account

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the accounts and customer total using an inline query that computes the customer and account totals within the same query.

```
SELECT
    product,
    colour,
    sum(price)total_price,
    (select count(DISTINCT  user_id) from transaction) as customer_total,
    (select count(DISTINCT account_id) from transaction) as account_total
 from transaction
 group by 
    product, colour
```

Result:

| product | colour | total_price | customer_total | account_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| biycle | black | 1525 | 3 | 8 |
| car | grey | 10000 | 3 | 8 |
| motorbike | black | 1250 | 3 | 8 |
| motorbike | blue | 1200 | 3 | 8 |
| motorbike | red | 1000 | 3 | 8 |
| scooter | blue | 260 | 3 | 8 |
| skateboard | white | 250 | 3 | 8 |

Comment: You need to add "order by product, colour" if you want to sort the data exactly as shown in your answer.

Comment: sorting is good but not always needed. when you pass the data to frontend, sorting maybe needed OR not at all needed.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to add this as further information. It's up to OP if they want it or not.